# putting a backslash before apostrophe

Tags: php, string, apostrophe

Which function processes a string putting a backslash before every apostrophes?
In other words, I want that

```
$string="L'isola";
echo somefunction($string);
```

returns:

```
L\'isola
```

Comment: I think you're after `addslashes`. However, don't use this for inserting data into databases - use parameterisation instead.

Comment: This should get you what you want: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8251426/insert-string-at-specified-position][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8251426/insert-string-at-specified-position

Comment: OP stated that he wants a backslash before every apostrophe, not that he wants every special character escaping.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use `addslashes()` method to escape the quote
Ex:

```
<?php
$str = "Is your name O'reilly?";

// Outputs: Is your name O\'reilly?
echo addslashes($str);
?>
```

and the reverse method is `stripslashes()` which remove slashes
Ex:

```
<?php
$str = "Is your name O\'reilly?";

// Outputs: Is your name O'reilly?
echo stripslashes($str);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use the `addslashes()` function more information can be found  [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php)

Answer (score 1):

str_replace will do that for you.

```
str_replace("'", "\'", $mystring);
```