# Split two strings in equal parts and add a word in between

Tags: php, string

I want to divide words in string by equal parts and then add something in middle.

```
$string = "hello i am superman and also batman";
$insert = "word";
```

so i want the result to be

```
$result= "hello i am superman word and also batman";
```

What  i tried...but below code is very dirty...any easy method please ?

```
$word = "word";
$arr = explode(" ",$string);
$count = round(sizeof($arr)/2);
$i=0;
foreach($arr as $ok)
{

if($i == $count)
{
$new.=$ok." ".$word;
}
else
{
$new.= $ok." ";
}
$i++;
}

echo trim($new);
```

Comment: What if the string is `"hello i am superman and I can fly faster than batman can"`?

Comment: result should be "hello i am superman and I word can fly faster than batman can"

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: This is just example ... i wanna add symbol in between actually..

Comment: Perhaps [How to insert element into array to specific position?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3353745/how-to-insert-element-into-array-to-specific-position) will help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [array_splice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php). An example below:

```
$string = "hello i am superman and also batman";
$insert = "word";

$string_array = explode(' ',$string);

array_splice( $string_array, round(count($string_array)/2), 0, array($insert) );

echo implode(' ', $string_array);
```

Or use it as a function:

```
function insertString($string, $insert){

    $string_array = explode(' ',$string);

    array_splice( $string_array, round(count($string_array)/2), 0, array($insert) );

    return implode(' ', $string_array);

}

echo insertString('hello i am superman and also batman','word');
```

Output will be:

```
hello i am superman word and also batman
```

Answer (score 1):

This is practically quite simple as long as you can accept a little lenience of splitting the string into "equal parts." In this scenario, I am considering the character count instead of the number of words. Use `strpos` to determine the position of the first space after the "halfway" point of the string:

```
$insertPoint = strpos($string, ' ', strlen($string) / 2);
```

Then inject the word there! (Used [this SO answer to achieve this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8251426/insert-string-at-specified-position))

```
$new = substr_replace($string, ' '.$insert, $insertPoint, 0);
```