# How to add a substring in a string with php

Tags: php, string

I need to have `Title, some text after comma` and the `Title` needs to be bold. I was thinking the way to do that would be to add `<strong>` tag at the beginning and somehow add a closing `</strong>` tag right before the comma.

I sort of found something that could do that: [Insert string at specified position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8251426/insert-string-at-specified-position) but it wasn't really working for me, maybe I did something wrong?

`$newstr = substr_replace($oldstr, '</strong>', substr($oldstr, ','), 0);` does not work for me. Any ideas on what's wrong there?

**Edit:** Why did I get a downvote?

Comment: This Looks like HTML code. So you should use a html Parser.

Comment: It wasn't me who downvoted. But I guess the reason would be that you didn't take a look at the official website of [PHP Substr()](http://php.net/substr). It would have told you why `substr` didn't work like that. It's just my guess though :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

are you mean this ?

```php
$str    = 'Hello World, i\'m here now';

$strEx  = explode(',', $str);

$title  = $strEx[0];

$text   = substr($str, strlen($title));

$strNew = '<strong>'.$title.'</strong>'.$text;

echo $strNew;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your `substr`. It doesn't take a comma as a second parameter. Instead the second parameter should be an integer as the starting point to take part of the string.

An easier solution would be:

```
$oldstr = "Title, this is a test";
$search = "/,/";
$replace = "</strong>,";

$newstr = preg_replace($search, $replace, $oldstr);

echo $newstr;
```

Answer (score 1):

if your case is like this **always** "Title, some text after comma", then you can replace the comma ',' with closing `</strong>`, and add `<strong>` at begin of string:

```
$str = "Title, some text after comma";
$result = "<strong>".str_replace(",","</strong>,",$str);
//<strong>Title</strong>, some text after comma
```

this way you will get what you need.