# PHP - add string to existing string at certain character position

Tags: php

I am trying to add  into a string at the 20th character position (making a collapser).

```
$link = '<span class="collapse"">'
$string = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam earum ex voluptate autem cupiditate tempora neque quis aliquam asperiores ab debitis nemo cumque, fuga quae, esse illum aut aliquid rem."

// Trying to add $link to $string at 20th character position
```

Comment: look here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8251426/insert-string-at-specified-position someone already asked similar

Answer (score 0):

Use [**`substr_replace()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php) It  Replace text within a portion of a string

```
$link = '<span class="collapse"">';
$string = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam earum ex voluptate autem cupiditate tempora neque quis aliquam asperiores ab debitis nemo cumque, fuga quae, esse illum aut aliquid rem.";

echo $newstr = substr_replace($string, $link, 20,0);
```

**[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/hHD59)**