# How to place script in dynamic paragraph

Tags: javascript, laravel, adsense

I have **google adsense** script which I can place it in different positions on my page.

I also have **body** text where the **description** of each `post` is and I want to know how can I add adsense script **dynamically** into my posts body text? (*Google suggested to place it after second paragraph*).

I am using `laravel` and this is how I get my body part of each post

```
{!! $post->body !!}
```

Sample of Google adsense code:

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
  style="display:block"
  data-ad-client="ca-pub-6565454545454774"
  data-ad-slot="548855465655"
  data-ad-format="auto"
  data-full-width-responsive="true"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

Any idea?

## Update

`single post function`

```
//single post
public function single($slug)
{
        $post = Post::where('slug', $slug)->where('publish', '=', 'y')->firstOrFail();

        $post->addPageView();

        $previous = Post::where('slug', '<', $post->slug)->max('slug');

        $next = Post::where('slug', '>', $post->slug)->min('slug');

        $products = Product::all()->where('status', 'enable')->random(3);

        $categories = PostCategory::all();

        $settings = Setting::all();

        $author = AuthorInfo::where('user_id', $post->user->id)->first();

        return view('front.singlepost', compact('post', 'previous', 'next', 'products','categories', 'settings','author'));
}
```

Comment: Can you update with the controller used for the `post` page?

Comment: Is `$post->body` text preformatted with html tags like paragraph tags? You could insert the adsense text into the `body` by finding the 2nd <p> [and using the `substr_replace` function.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17880260/3585500)

Comment: @ourmandave yes it will print content of post body like `<p>....</p>` and whatever else we put while creating that content in ckeditor.

Comment: @thisiskelvin i just get posts base on their `slug` and then in blade getting different column of each post like `$post->body` nothing special about controller part, however here it is:  `$post = Post::where('slug', $slug)->where('publish', '=', 'y')->firstOrFail();`

Comment: @ourmandave sorry but i didn't get how to use that `substr_replace` PS: I included my controller part in previous comment if it helps.

Comment: @mafortis In what part of your code will be you adding your dynamic adsense code?

Comment: @thisiskelvin currently I just placed javascript code provided by google in blade (nothing in back-end)

Comment: @mafortis So is each google adsense script unique to the post?

Comment: Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36276123/3585500) on how to put adsense in blog posts.

Comment: @thisiskelvin no script is the same as my sample code in question i just want to place it after second paragraph of my `$post->body`

Comment: @mafortis You mean after the first `<p>` tag?

Comment: @thisiskelvin after second one but even after first is ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't had a chance to test this out, however you can create an `accessor` (in this case `getBodyWithAdsenseAttribute`) which will create an altered version of the body content and include the adsense content after the **2nd** paragraph:

Within your `Post` model file:

```
public function getBodyWithAdsenseAttribute()
{
    $javascript = '<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
    <ins class="adsbygoogle"
      style="display:block"
      data-ad-client="ca-pub-6565454545454774"
      data-ad-slot="548855465655"
      data-ad-format="auto"
      data-full-width-responsive="true"></ins>
    <script>
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    </script>';

    $paragraphs  = explode('</p>', $this->body); // Explode current body field
    $new_content = ''; // Variable for new content
    $count       = 1; // Set count for adding new content

    foreach ($paragraphs as $paragraph) {
        $new_content .= $paragraph;

        if ($count == 2) {
            $new_content .= $javascript;
        }

        $count++;
    }

    return $new_content;
}
```

Here, we store all the adsense data within a `$javascript` variable.

We then `explode()` the `body` content by the closing `</p>` tag, creating an array from the content.

Using a `foreach()`, we recreate the `body` content, counting to see if it is after the **2nd** instance of the `</p>` tag. If so, we add the `$javascript` content to the new content.

Finally, we return all the content. This can be used within blade like the following

```
{!! $post->bodyWithAdsense !!}
```

**Note**: More code will be needed to fallback in case there is only one paragraph, or if there is no body content at all.

Comment: thank you s much, i will try this and let you know about the result

Comment: in 3 hours i will test it, sorry for delay. I'm night shift :)

Comment: it removed my body content.

Comment: Does your body definitely have `<p>` tags?

Comment: `accessors` don't work like that. Once created, you need to take out `set` and `attribute`. Can you post your controller in your question please.

Comment: sure i will now

Comment: what is `$post->addPageView()` doing?

Comment: that counting posts visits it's package

Comment: Sorry. It is not `set` it is `get`. I'll change my answer. Apologies.

Comment: i'm getting `Whoops, looks like something went wrong.`

Comment: the error detail: `Trying to get property 'body' of non-object (View: `

Comment: Updated answer. Please remove suggestion to add `$value` in parameter, and just use `$this`. Should work after.

Comment: ok it is working :) thank you. But can we provide div around it in our code? i need to make some spaces.

Comment: Thank you, please mark as correct. You can add a div around in the blade template. No need to do this within the controller code.

Comment: I meant around adsense code, it's too much close to texts in my post body i want make some space with css.

Comment: Just find the class name that is given to the created adsense area. Should be the same every time