# how to add a specific letter in a specific word in php

Tags: php, html

Hello everyone I am new on PHP, in my case I want to add a specific letter in a specific word in the sentence.

For example :

I have a function that returns this string in html => "Order #00000001000" ,
I want to add a letter "P" after the "#" like this => "Order #P00000001000",

PS : I don't want to change it in the function, I just want to change it in the HTML directly

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert string at specified position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8251426/insert-string-at-specified-position)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `substr_replace`. The code below says: on the 7th place of string `$withoutP` insert the letter P.

```
<?php
$withoutP = "Order #000000022";
$withP = substr_replace($withoutP, 'P', 7, 0);

echo $withP;
```

If you can't assume the string always has the word Order in it, you can use a combination of `implode`, `explode` and `substr_replace`.

```
<?php
$withoutP = "Order #000000022";
$exploded = explode("#", $withoutP);
$exploded[1] = substr_replace($exploded[1], 'P', 0, 0);

$withP =  implode("#", $exploded);
echo $withP;
```

Comment: thanks for your response , but i have some issue , i can't assume that the string has always the word 'Order ' it can be in French with 'Commande' , so is there any idea to test just on the number "#000000022" , for example using the explode and implode functions

Comment: Yes, absolutely, I've added an example.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont know the position of "#", use this :

```
$pos=strpos($withoutP, "#");
$withP = substr_replace($withoutP, 'P', $pos, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo substr_replace($oldstr, 'P', 7, 0); ?>
```

taken from: [Insert string at specified position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8251426/insert-string-at-specified-position)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str_replace` function

```
function addP($text) {
   return str_replace('Order #', 'Order #P', $text);
}
```